# Asp.net Web api fails in publishing with no error

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, publish

My web api project fails with no error in publish, while the project build result is succeeded

[image: This is the result]

Comment: I see just 7 succeeded, apparently they are 8 projects. Do you have anything in the output window other than these? try to scroll up. Do you have any error in the `Error/Warning` window?

Comment: there are 9 projects in solution, but this project has reference to 6 other project, So the 7 succeeded is ok.there is no error in the output.

Comment: Clean the solution and rebuild.  Why do you say its failing if there are no errors?  Is it possible those projects just aren't getting built?

Comment: @Amy I tried that too, but it didn't work. All the projects get build successfully, but when it comes to publishing it fails.